# Apply "Floating/Translucent Window" to all existing sticky notes?

Tags: software-recommendation

If I have a large number of sticky notes on my desktop, each of which a varying permutation of "Floating/Translucent Window", is there a way to "Select All" stickies and apply the "Floating/Translucent Window" operation to them all?

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to do this. Stickies does not have a preferences section nor does it have a .plist file to modify. Everything is stored in a StickiesDatabase file within your user directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set Floating Window as the default behavior for all new stickies, but for existing stickies you will need to set this value one-by-one.

**To set the default:**
On one sticky (any sticky), click Note from the menu bar and set "Floating Window" and/or "Translucent Window" to *checked*.  Then select "Use as Default" from the same menu.

[image: Screenshot showing the menu selections described above.]

All new stickies will have the new settings.  You can turn these off on a sticky-by-sticky basis, or you can re-set the defaults using the these instructions.